# General performance php / [big framework like doctrine / symfony]

Tags: php, performance, symfony, doctrine-orm

Is a PHP application (using doctrine as ORM mapping and or Symfony or other big frameworks) suitable for a high load application? I mean especially the thing that every time a php file is called by a website or app the whole framework project gets loaded. Because to use the framework I need to inlcude the "autoloader" file and in this file the whole project (my project and the framework) gets loaded and go into memory. 
So when I imagine that my server has 100 Requests per second and every request means call file.php -> include autoload.php -> autoloading the WHOLE framework files -> do something -> send output to user -> close connection, this can get really memory intensive?

Or is there something like a cache, that when Request 1) is loading the whole php files (framework) into memory and Request 2) comes 1ms later, it can use the files from memory?

Maybe somebody can help me to understand, how PHP internally works.

I am using FPM (FastCGI Process Manager) on my webserver.

Comment: Here's an article on Symfony performance .. [here](http://symfony.com/blog/push-it-to-the-limits-symfony2-for-high-performance-needs)

Comment: Don't mean to sound snarky but are you seriously trying to design a 100 requests per second application without any knowledge of caching or php in general?

Comment: It was an extreme example to show what my concern is. Let it be 10 request per second or 1 per second, just wanted to know if the autoloader loads the whole thing into memory and this every new time a new requests comes in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, autoloading doesn't necessarily mean that the whole framework gets loaded into the memory. For example composer's autoloader only loads the required class when the class is actually instantiated. So the main point of autoloading function is to load only what is needed.

If you are using php5.5+ then you have opcache which reduces the load and load-times of php applications because php opcodes can be loaded from cache. If you are using php7 then it is even faster. I have built several applications with doctrine and so far there haven't been any roadblocks. Yes having ORM as an abstraction layer for database has an overhead but does it outweigh having spaghetti code instead? yes. If you were to compare PDO to lets say Doctrine2? PDO wins. But you can fine-tune doctrine with query and metadata caches etc. I personally use doctrine with redis cache and it is fairly fast.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I use php7. It wasn't clear to me what the composer autoloader actually loads. I thought that it just loads every class, but when it loads only what is need (classes imported with "use"?) then its okay.

Comment: It doesnt't even load the class when u call "use", it only loads the class when you instantiate it / call a static method or access static variable. Under the hood it uses spl_autoload_register to register a callback that handles the autoloading. see http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php